# How do I combine several images into one?

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I have several images (3rd parties) which eg setup a mysql, set up a generic php app environment, set up 3rd parties tools.

I want to make a Dockerfile / Docker Image which combines both those images and then runs some more commands

```
imageA --
            \
imageV --    ---> sharedImageA..X
            /
imageX --
```

Comment: Do they all have the same parent image? If not then what you are asking is not possible

Comment: Sometimes yes,  (parent for layer before) and no

Comment: I've posted an answer, but as you understand you can't combine images that depend on different OS or different version of the same OS

Comment: Even though you can create a single Dockerfile containing steps to install all the dependent packages, make sure you start all the dependent services as well. When you run separate images, each image has a separate `entrypoint`. When you merge them together, you need to make sure that all the services which were getting started in the previous images are started in this single image as well. For that, you can write a script and put it at entrypoint.

Comment: Multiple separate apps is a hint that docker-compose may be a better solution to the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can chain them. You can find more here

https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/3378#issuecomment-31314906

Taken from the above link

```
## Dockerfile.genericwebapp might have FROM ubuntu
cat Dockerfile.genericwebapp | docker build -t genericwebapp -
## Dockerfile.genericpython-web would have FROM genericwebapp
cat Dockerfile.genericpython-web | docker build -t genericpython-web -
## and then this specific app i'm testing might have a docker file that containers FROM genericpython-web
docker build -t thisapp .
```

*author of the above* [SvenDowideit](https://github.com/SvenDowideit)

In general though, it's a bad practice to have more than one running processes on the same container.

Comment: you could at least point to the comment you refer too, that's a long thread

Comment: It's the second comment. Updated the answer

Answer (score 1):

Since dependencies from seconds and third image can conflict with dependencies from first image, I don't think docker would able to support it.

I guess the only option is to start your image from 1 of them an then install/run all of the steps from 2 others:

```
FROM imageA
RUN .... commands for imageV
RUN .... commands for imageX
```