# Docker unique container

Tags: docker

I have a docker with 3 images and i want to link them.

A elastic-search image, a kibana image and a panthomJS.

I had up 3 containers different with the images, but i don't want this, i want to create a docker-file to up a unique container with the three images.

I've already pull the images to use.
I looked on dockerhub and i found this:

https://hub.docker.com/r/nshou/elasticsearch-kibana/

It's just it i want to do ,but with the third image

Any help?

Comment: Maybe this helps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36801509/how-do-i-combine-several-images-into-one

Comment: Though I do not know your use case, I don't think that it would be wise to do this. Why not use docker-compose and up them together?

Comment: Why do you need to join them? The docker way is to have them separately