# How to import several image with docker import?

Tags: linux, docker, unix, command-line-interface

*My topic's not about imort several image inside one container but in my Docker local repository.*

I have tried:

```
docker import  '/home/ulimwengu/docker_images/*'
```

But it returns me:

> no such file or directory

But it doesn't work. What can I do ?

Any hint would be great,
thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Multiple images inside one container](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45229777/608639), [How do I combine several images into one?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36801509/608639), [What is the impact of using multiple Base Images in Docker?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18601640/608639), etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Load them with a short bit of shell script

```
for i in /home/ulimwengu/docker_images/*; do docker import "$i";done
```

Comment: thanks for the hint, it returns me  syntax error: unexpected end of file